# non available row in result group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I used the following query

```
select month(SubmittedDate), count(policyid) from tblpolicy p join tlkppolicystatus s on p.StatusID=s.StatusID where SubmittedDate between 
'2017-01-01' and sysdate()  and s.StatusID=1 group by month(SubmittedDate);
```

This returns the following output which is correct as month number 3 and 4 don't have any data.

```
Month  Total
-----|-----
1    | 62
2    | 34
5    | 1
```

But I want the output to be like

```
Month  Total
-----|-----
1    | 62
2    | 34
3    | 0
4    | 0
5    | 1
```

So that means if any month do have any data then also it will show with a value 0

Thanks

Comment: use a left join

Comment: _**@OP**_: you have to use dummy master months list from which you can compare and show from the actual data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data for all months, but none of the data has a status of 1, then the simplest method is probably to use conditional aggregation:

```
select month(SubmittedDate), sum(s.StatusID = 1)
from tblpolicy p join
     tlkppolicystatus s
     on p.StatusID=s.StatusID
where SubmittedDate between '2017-01-01' and sysdate()
group by month(SubmittedDate);
```

Of course, if those conditions don't hold, then the `left join` with a derived table is the best solution.

Comment: But how to apply this logic in the following query ?

select month(SubmittedDate), ROUND(sum(points) / count(policyid))  from tblpolicy  where SubmittedDate between '2017-01-01' and sysdate() and ProductType
= 'Annuity' group by month(SubmittedDate);

Comment: @user1795928 . . . That is not the question being asked.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.  It is rude to change the question in such a way that existing answers are invalidated -- that can draw downvotes.

Comment: okay, we'll delete this comment. Can't you help me here by writing the answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select coalesce(t1.month,t2.month) as month, coalesce(ct1.count,0) as count from 
(
select month(SubmittedDate) as month, count(policyid) as count 
 from tblpolicy p join tlkppolicystatus s on p.StatusID=s.StatusID 
 where SubmittedDate between 
'2017-01-01' and sysdate()  and s.StatusID=1 group by month(SubmittedDate)
) as t1 right join 
(
select 1 as month union all
select 2 as month union all
select 3 as month union all
select 4 as month union all
select 5 as month union all
select 6 as month union all
select 7 as month union all
select 8 as month union all
select 9 as month union all
select 10 as month union all
select 11 as month union all
select 12 as month 
) as t2 on t1.month <= t2.month;
```

Comment: Hi Madhivanan, Can we have an way which will only display months till the date range given. Like here in my query it's jan  - may so month should be till 5 only. This date value will be passed dynamically so this is really important.